# Using current lat/lng to query database and return data to user in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

So I have an issue where I want to be able to query some data with the user's current location but I am still new to JSON and trying to figure out how to send the data back to the main page.

Here are the hidden inputs for the lat/lng values on the index.php page

```
<input type="hidden" id="latitude">
<input type="hidden" id="longitude">
```

Here is the code to send the lat/lng to tables.php from the index.php page

```
 $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
     $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
     $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
        $.ajax({
            url:'table.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
                 lat: $('#latitude').val(),
                 lng: $('#longitude').val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log();
            }
        });             
   });
```

I am using datatables to display the data on the index.php page.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var dataTable = $('#searchTable').dataTable();
            $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
                dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
            });
        });  
        </script>

        echo'<table id="searchTable" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Latitude</th>
                        <th>Longitude</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                ';

                (data to display from tables.php)

        echo'</tbody>
            </table>
                ';
```

And then on the tables.php page I am pulling the data from the MYSQL database, now this is where I have to figure out how to send the data back to the index.php page through JSON and display it in the table.

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");

$lat = isset($_POST['lat']) ? $_POST['lat'] : null;
$lng = isset($_POST['lng']) ? $_POST['lng'] : null;

if($lat && $lng){

    $locations = array();       

    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM location LIMIT 500"; //Query data from table
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach($result as $row){ 
             echo'<tr>
                <td>';              
                   $locations['Latitude'][] = $row;
                echo'</td>
                <td>';
                   $locations['Longitude'][] = $row;    
                echo'</td>
             </tr>';        
        }
    }
     return json_encode($locations);
}
?>
```

What I am looking to do is update the table with data from the database based on the user's current location, when the user lands on the index.php page, Or the user can also search for a location using the search bar provided on the index.php page.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Use .val() instead of html()

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify. What I want to accomplish:  When the user visits the website, I want to display information based on the users location. So if you are from L.A. California, then the table will display all the information for that location automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first send JSON correctly from PHP file, and then receive at the AJAX response and parse to use it further to show in data tables. See below codes for the help.

**Client side code:**

```
$.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
 $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
 $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
    $.ajax({
        url:'table.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
             lat: $('#latitude').val(),
             lng: $('#longitude').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
                            // Here you need to parse the JSON data and put it in the data table rows by looping over it, see example code #E1                               
            console.log();
        }
    });             
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php require_once("connect.php"); $lat = isset($_POST['lat']) ? $_POST['lat'] : null; $lng = isset($_POST['lng']) ? $_POST['lng'] : null; if($lat && $lng){ $locations = array(); $stmt = "SELECT * FROM location LIMIT 500"; //Query data from table $stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);$stmt->execute(); if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){ $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); foreach($result as $row){
$result[] = ['col1'=>$row['col1'],'col2'=>$row['col2']]; // here you need to add as many columns as you want to show in the data table } } print json_encode($result);die; } ?>
```

**Example codes:-**

```
_#E1_
console.log(JSON.stringify(json.topics)); $.each(json.topics, function(idx, topic){ $("#nav").html('<a href="' + topic.link_src + '">' + topic.link_text + "</a>"); });
```

Apply code as per your need and it will resolve your problem. Assuming you are getting proper data from the database query.

Hope it helps.

Thanks